# iOS - Configuring Custom UITableViewCell on VIPER pattern

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, design-patterns, viper-architecture

I have been following **VIPER** design pattern for my current **iOS (Swift)** project and i am new on using design pattern on code. I am having trouble to take decision about customizing or configuring a subclass of `UITableViewCell`. Do i change the cell's on `ViewController`'s -> 
`func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell` this delegate method or on my derived `UITableViewCell`'s class instance method's ?? Actually the work is changing cell's `IBOutlets` like Label, ImageView from Model data

Answer (score 2):

I think you should change your cell inside cell because you're not breaking the encapsulation and can make your `IBOutlets` private.

Actually you can incapsulate you `UITableViewDelegate` and `UITableViewDataSource` realisation in some object. We're creating `TableViewAdapter` for this. You can find example of `TableViewAdapter` in my open source VIPER example [here](https://github.com/ismetanin/ViperDemo/blob/master/ViperDemo/Classes/Presentation/UserStories/PersonList/View/PersonListAdapter.swift).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I will try